# Instabot: Is it possible to upload multiple images in a single post?

Tags: python

I am using this code to create a simple daily post bot for Instagram.

It's all going well but would be incredible if I could post albums of 2 - 3 images in each post.

Is this possible?

Here's what I've made so far which works perfectly for single-image posts…

```
import os
import random
import shutil
import time
import schedule

from PIL import Image
from instabot import Bot

def get_image_and_post():
path = r"……………"
file_name = random.choice([x for x in os.listdir(path) if not x.startswith(".")])
fullpath = path + "/" + file_name
img = Image.open(fullpath)
img.save(file_name)

destination = "…………"
shutil.move(fullpath, destination)
os.remove(destination + '/' + file_name)

title_caption = file_name.replace("-", " ") \
.replace(".jpeg", "") \
.replace(".jpg", "")

my_hashtags = "……………"
caption_final = title_caption + "\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n" + my_hashtags

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username="…………", password="…………")
bot.upload_photo("…………" + file_name, caption=caption_final)

print(caption_final + " ————> Posted!")
```

I just need to know if this is a possibility? I've found nowhere else asking this.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Nice work! I'm in the same task right now. I was wondering if you found a way to distinguish if an image is horizontal or vertical, to upload it on the correct orientation. Thanks!

Comment: There used to be a function called upload_album in instabot. Apparently they removed it between the versions - couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that is possible with **instaBot** but i managed to do it by using **instagrapi**.

```py
from instagrapi import Client

bot = Client()
bot.login(Username, Password)

album_path = [".../Image1.jpg", ".../Image2.jpg"]
text =  "Hello"

bot.album_upload(
    album_path,
    caption = text
)
```