# Instagrapi: Please wait a few minutes before you try again. WHY?

Tags: python

I used the code from @Xerneas 02, only it gives me this error.

[This Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67028932/15870691)

```
from instagrapi import Client

bot = Client()

bot.login("username", "password")

album_path = ["immagini/81/Home/1.jpeg", "immagini/81/Home/2.jpeg", "immagini/81/Home/3.jpeg",
"immagini/81/Home/4.jpeg", "immagini/81/Home/5.jpeg", "immagini/81/Home/6.jpeg","immagini/81/Home/7.jpeg"]

text =  "text"

bot.album_upload(
   album_path,
   caption = text
)
```

This is the error:

```
instagrapi.exceptions.PleaseWaitFewMinutes: Please wait a few minutes before you try again.
```

i also tried uninstalling and reinstalling instagrapi.

how can i fix it

i also tried to change instagram account, but nothing. have I banned the ip address

Comment: Seems like you might have blocked your IP? See this issue: https://github.com/adw0rd/instagrapi/issues/135

Answer (score 0):

Try to use proxy

```
from instagrapi import Client
    
bot = Client()
bot.set_proxy("http://<PROXY_LOGIN>:<PROXY_PWD>@<IP>:<PORT>")
bot.login("username", "password")
```